# How to draw 1216 canvas elements without hanging application in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I am developing an app I want to add some cool icons. Because I am using the beautiful MahApps library, I want to have a visual on the icons in MahApps.Metro/MahApps.Metro.Resources/Icons.xaml, so I did some string manipulations to grab the `x:Key` part of each `<Canvas x:Key="appbar_3d_3ds" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">` line. In short, all the string manipulations I did ended up with 1216 copies of the following:

```
<controls:Tile
Title="appbar_zune" Count="1215" Grid.Row="121" Grid.Column="15" TiltFactor="2" Width="1*" Height="1*"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
<Rectangle Margin="0" Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=Foreground}">
<Rectangle.OpacityMask>
<VisualBrush Stretch="Fill"
Visual="{StaticResource appbar_zune}" />
</Rectangle.OpacityMask>
</Rectangle>
</controls:Tile>
```

Note that each copy of the `<control:Tile` has the appropriate properties `Count`, `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` correctly set.

However, I always end up with the `Application not responding` window message. Now as I said, my motive is just to get a visual on that collection of pretty icons and instead I get a fat application crash. I just want to know if there is a way to display such a huge collection without crashing anybody's computer (Note: the system is really low on RAM: one of my test machines that run inside virtualbox).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make your Fill binding have Mode=OneWay. I bet you don't need it to be TwoWay and it may be the defalt in your setup. TwoWay bindings cost much more.

Second, consider using ever harsher version: Mode=OneTime. Since the icons are unlikely to change, you don't need any change tracking at all. This will save you even more resources.

In your case, First+Second will probably not give you a huge boost, but it's worth trying and remembering.

Third, how about your `VisualBrush`es? Do all of them use the same `Visual="{StaticResource appbar_zune}"`? Then why do you create thousands of instances? Instead of copy-pasting, create just one instance and make all items use that one instance. You may save much time and memory.

Fourth, and most important and usually giving the greatest speedup, is - you have **tons** of items. I bet you have some scrolling, horizontal or vertical. But how do you generate and display those pile of items? Creating them ALL at once is .. wasteful. They don't fit all on screen, right?

Do you have some ItemsControl that generate that thousand items? Investigate the `ItemsPanel` property of that ItemsControl and turn on `virtualizing` option on that panel. This will cause it to link to the scrollbar and it will start dynamically creating only those items that are on-screen and destroying items that moved off-screen. Well, I oversimplified it, but letssay it works like that. Note that containers like `ListBox` (and many others) is an ItemsControl too, so it also applies here.

Or maybe you have huge explicit XAML file with that thousand controls inside some `StackPanel` with no ItemsControl? That's not really wise. But oh well.. you can still turn on `virtualization` on that StackPanel.

Turning on virtualization usually is a good idea if you have more than few tens of items. It's often a must of you have a hundred, and it is a must if you reach thousands and more. However, virtualization costs: it very often resets/reinitializes items. If your ItemTemplate is really complex, virtualization may cause the scrolling to became "jaggy/laggy", I don't know how to express that in english, sorry. The compositor thread may simply not have enough time to recalculate and relayout all the fast moving items. If you hit that problem, try setting the `Height` of the Items to a unchanging truly fixed constant value. It helps greatly in speeding up the layout. but if your ItemTemplate is really wickedly complex, it may not help either. In such dead-end case your only option is ... redesign and to simplify the item template.

EDIT:

Of course all of that won't gain you anything if you don't have scrollbar and if you are trying to display a ton of items at once. In this case, strive to simplify or remove Bindings, Templates, component nesting (sometimes it's better to calculate positions manually than using three embeded Grids), [use rendering cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230083%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or  (...).. Sorry, I start making too many guesses, too many options..

EDIT:

I just noticed `Width="1*"` and `Stretch`, so you probably have a Grid at the top, not StackPanel. Since you want them equally-sized, the `UniformGrid` may have better performance. Also, with some work you can add virtualizing to the Grids, too:

- from 4.5 and up, it's much easier - [article: WPF 4.5 new virtualizing features](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/10/07/wpf-4-5-%E2%80%93-part-11-new-features-for-the-virtualizingpanel/)
- below, it requires more work, see Dan Crevier's 4-part series blog:

  - One: http://blogs.msdn.com/dancre/archive/2006/02/06/implementing-a-virtualized-panel-in-wpf-avalon.aspx
  - Two: http://blogs.msdn.com/dancre/archive/2006/02/13/531550.aspx
  - Three: http://blogs.msdn.com/dancre/archive/2006/02/14/532333.aspx
  - Four: http://blogs.msdn.com/dancre/archive/2006/02/16/implementing-a-virtualizingpanel-part-4-the-goods.aspx
    If virtualizing the Grid is not enough, try moving to Canvas instead and force some width/height/positions manually. Removing automatic layouting sometimes saves a lot. Then, you can use [VirtualizedCanvas](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/03/08/performant-virtualized-wpf-canvas.aspx) and if you really put there constant-sized items, you'll probably get it as fast as possible. But that's a last-resort option. Things mentioned earlier should work well.

Oh, and one last word about virtualizing: remember that when ScrollView is working in virtualizing mode, then the `Position` is not counted in pixels/points anymore. In v-mode, the Position of the scrollbar is counted in `items`, that is, position=2.5 means that the scroller is at halfway through the third item (2 items passed and a half more), not at pos=2.5 "pixels".

---

Side note: "million point canvas": https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaelr/2010/08/11/zoomableapplication2-a-million-items/

Comment: No, `Visual="{StaticResource <iconKey>}` is generated for each icon key, so `appbar_zune` is just one of those keys. Note that they whole code excerpt in my question (the whole `<controls:Tile>` tag) was auto-generated by a separate c# code by reading the `C:\\Users\\myAccount\\MahApps.Metro/MahApps.Metro.Resources/Icons.xaml` file and using the `x:Key` definition to generate 1216 variants of such `<controls:Tile>` tag (with logic that handles `Margin`, `Grid.Column` and `Grid.Row`). So no `Binding` is going on. So are you saying I can use `Binding` to generate `UIElements`?

Comment: @emmanuel: Not directly via `Binding`, but indirectly yes. That's what components like `ContentPresenter` or `ItemsControl` are. If you had a `List<T>` with T being a class that keeps all information about the icon, then you could use `<ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding pathtoyourlist}>` and the itemscontrol would generate you a list of items synced 1-to-1 to that source list. The items would be generated according to the ItemTemplate that you also need to set on that ItemsControl

Comment: @emmanuel: In basic usage, ItemsControl generate all items as soon as it gets the data from the binding. But if virtualization is turned on, it will only generate the part that is currently on-screen, potentially saving much time and memory. By default virt is off, because it costs and is not always possible.

Comment: @emmanuel: I'm actually very suprised you have written code-generator for making that XAML. Using ItemsControl is very easy and covered in many lectures/tutorials, so I assumed you are already doing it like that. "ItemsControl" is the base component of every "repeater"-type components in WPF/Silverlight/.., sometimes it's easier to come by `ListBox` first. ListBox is an "upgraded" ItemsControl with more features, ItemsControl is lighter and easier to "tailor" to your needs.

Comment: @emmanuel: if you were not using IC/LB earlier, please start with ListBox. [ListBox has virtualization turned on by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). [Simple&quick tutorial about listbox](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/listbox-control/) - note that LBItems can be created by hand in XAML ListBox.ItemTemplate set. Then the tutorial has LisBox's ItemSource set manually in the C#, but ItemSource is a DepProp so it can have a Binding set in XAML too.

Comment: you have nailed this one completely. Bravo!