# WPF canvas render performance on large number of UIelements

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, webgl

I'm familiar with html5 canvas, I wanted to use something similar with c# .NET, WPF canvas looks similar enough.

I have an application is constantly receiving 2d points as input and draws them on the canvas, I do this by adding children of points to the collection. As time passes by the application starts to get bogged down, no surprise the amount of children the wpf canvas has to redraw each time is increasing linearly.

I don't want any of the bitmap solutions I saw on the other posts, because as far has I know you dont't have a render matrix, where you can scale translate and skew.

I want something similar with html5 where it just draws the point on canvas as a line an then only when I need to translate or scale I have to redraw.

Can I use that with wpf canvas for that?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, but it's pretty now what you'd expect. That may take significant amount of work for you. WPF generally handles well up to 1000-10000 live on-screen items, depending on how complex their visual templates are and how often databinding refreshes occur. However, it can be heavily optimized for more items. This question was asked before and I remember providing links to articles that described exactly the same, or similar problem.. Gimme a sec..

Comment: Got it - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27871828/717732

Comment: Hm.. actually, it's a duplicate..

Comment: aaah the same probelm but not that links, ALMOST... just a little bit more

Comment: Yes I might have read that, the problem is that it is constantly adding new points to the screen, it might have a million points on screen. If have to redraw them every time, that will bogged down sometime, but if draw them and they stay there until I want to refresh the screen, in case of zoom or something like that only then will it be redraw. So I want something like html5 where you draw and it stays there, no need for UIcollection.

Comment: Found it! > https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaelr/2010/08/11/zoomableapplication2-a-million-items/

Comment: Check that article, it directly touches "million point" goal. While it's not 100% satisfying, it uses some "dirty tricks", the net effect in most applications is great. For a better effect, you need to add some throttling (you can force full rebind every 1ms!), point grouping (1mil? you wont see it, group close points together), and similar mechanisms.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl how is it the same question?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I want something that doesn't need to redraw everything all the time. If I understand the article tweaks the approach of drawing everything every time. Maybe I wasn't too clear. But thanks for the article.

Comment: `how is it the same question?` - I got that impression, because you defined the problem in the title as "WPF canvas render performance on large number of UIelements [duplicate]". The question I marked as dupe, and links contained there, all describe solutions for that problem. It could be simplified to bitmap-wise solutions, which you can aggressively cache and scroll, but you explicitly said you don't want it (even though if it's a "line" (measurement graph?) then bitmap is probably the most natural thing?)

Comment: so, if bitmaps are out, then you have to use data virtualization, aggressive data-binding optimizations, etc, - all described in that articles.. But, if I guess right and it's a chart that's drawn over time and grows with new data, please reconsider both bitmaps (it does not need to be ONE, you may have segments, and cache-reuse-scroll the "old" ones, without redrawing, while drawing only the N most recent data on the last-newest segment, etc)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl will have a look then at the bitmap again, maybe Ill implement a transformation matrix by hand, and make the CPU transform every new point. Shame html5 canvas isn't that similar with wpf canvas. Thanks again.

Comment: or data (pre)aggregation - if you have many points, say 1 measurement per 1..3 seconds, and got 1year of data, then fully zooming in and showing 1000-4000pts from a single hour is fine, but zooming out kills the performance. Thing to notice here is that zooming out yields more data points than pixels on the screen. Upon zooming-out, pre-aggregate (group) the data, so you don't ask WPF to draw 1000dots in the same X-Y pixel location - it's just wasteful.

Comment: Is there a way to draw in a bmp, and then put that bmp on the canvas? would it be fast?

Comment: `I'll implement a transformation matrix by hand, and make the CPU transform every new point` - yes, if you use RenderTransform to do move/"scroll" old bitmaps out of sight pixel-by-pixel/etc it will be very fast, as GPU will just offset it with no work on CPU.

Comment: `Is there a way to draw in a bmp, and then put that bmp on the canvas? would it be fast?` - it depends on what you mean on "draw". WPF cannot read a mutable bitmap. Any bitmap given to WPF must be frozen and immutable. In fact, WPF **will copy** any bitmap you give it him. That means that simple approaches will use at least 3 copies of the bitmap - your writeable is one, one for keeping in databinding engine, and one somewhere on GPU. If you do it carefully, and ensure it's properly immutable, you can unify the one "yours" and "in databinding engine" but the one in GPU is out of reach.

Comment: Furthermore, since WPF/GPU **require** them to be immutable, any update to source bitmap, propagated by databindings, will force refreshing all of those copies in the chain. This **can kill performance** if updates are often and/or if bitmaps are large.

Comment: That's why I referred to segments. Say you've got 1000 points. Draw them on a, say, 1000x300 bitmap. Freeze the bitmap properly. Give it to WPF. Remember that bitmap. Never change it. Show it on canvas via normal `<Image` and `BitmapSource`. New point arrives? RenderTransform/Translate that bitmap 1px to the left. Create new bitmap 200x300 bitmap. Draw new point on it. Add it to canvas, translated 199px to right, so only 1pt is visible. Keep bitmap mutable, keep scrolling oldest segment as well. Draw next 199 points on it current one. After 200th, freeze the bitmap, rinse, repeat.

Comment: ^ numbers and bitmap sizes are just for example. I'd start with such, but you may need to optimize it for your case. The best effect of this approach is that all bitmaps are moved by RenderTransform, so are sent to GPU once and re-used, except for the "current segment" which is relatively small and cost of its copying-buffers-via-WPF-layers-on-every-new-point-added is acceptable.

Comment: On the bitmap rinse repeat why do I have to translate it to the left and right to make them visible? Thanks for the really helpful help.

Comment: Screen pixels:  `oooooooooo`; Initial bitmap has width: 5, buffer symbol `x`, data symbol: `X`. Initial content of `x`: `XXXXX`. Display it. Screen effect. `XXXXXooooo`. New data point. Previous buffer full (5/5), nonwritable. We have no buffer. We create new buffer bitmap: width: 2, symbol `z`, data symbol: `Z1`. Initial content: `zz`. Write point. Curr content: `Zz`. Display it. Need to translate to-right by RenderTransform X+5 (sizeof prev buff): `XXXXXZzooo`. Get new point, prev buffer full in 1/2 - writable. Write, display: `XXXXXZZooo`. Next 2 points, new buff 'A' > `XXXXXZZAAo`

Comment: While initial offsets set more-to-right are more-or-less obvious, because we want to "glue them up" edge-to-edge, not make them cover/overlay each one on another. We now have `XXXXXZZAAo`, this is when fun starts. New point arrives. First `x` is full 5/5, second `z` is 2/2, third `a` is 2/2, we get new buff: `b`, data marked as `B`, output: `XXXXXZZAAB|b`. The "tail" of the buffer is out-of-screen. When yet new point arrives, we write it to curr.open.buf `b`: `BB`, but it's out of screen. What do we do? We have to RenderTransform ALL of them by X-=1: `XXXXXZZAAB|B` -> `X|XXXXZZAABB`

Comment: For every new point arriving, we always have to "scroll" the chart leftwards, and we have to let old points, and then even old buffers "fall out of the canvas". We can keep them for scrolling the chart with scrollbars, or we can drop them off the screen to save memory, whatever. The point is that by default, when the measurement is running, you always have some "time range" to show, hence you always show only the last N points, written over last M buffers. Changing the "zoom" only changes those parameters. And "buffers" can be always cached and never redrawn until chart settings are changed.

Comment: ^`last N points, written over last M buffers` - and since you know the current width-in-pixels of the chart, you can always detect if there are too many points of a buffer (i.e. 1000points drawn in a buffer if 50px width?) and you can squash/aggregate/group/ignore/delete/etc the points before drawing/etc.